# TensorBoard Callbacks in Keras Backend Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In order to get training and graph information of a CNN in Keras, I simply define `tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="CNN/Logs/{}".format(MODEL_ID))` and then add `callbacks=[tensorboard]` to the `fit()` method of my model.

I am implementing a Policy Network following [this](https://gist.github.com/kkweon/c8d1caabaf7b43317bc8825c226045d2) example, and am wondering now how I can get training and graph information of the PN in Tensorboard.

Possibly there is a callbacks equivalent in Keras Backend's `function()`, I have not had any hope with the documentation.

Specifically, my equivalent of `fit()` looks as follows:

```
def build_train_fn(self):
    """ Train function for the Policy Network.

    This function replaces model.fit(X, y).
    """

    with self.graph.as_default():

        K.set_session(self.session)

        action_prob_placeholder = self.model.output
        action_onehot_placeholder = K.placeholder(shape=(None, ACTIONS), name="action_onehot")
        discount_reward_placeholder = K.placeholder(shape=(None,), name="discount_reward")

        action_prob = K.sum(action_prob_placeholder * action_onehot_placeholder, axis=1)
        log_action_prob = K.log(action_prob)

        loss = - log_action_prob * discount_reward_placeholder
        loss = K.mean(loss)

        adam = optimizers.Adam()

        updates = adam.get_updates(params=self.model.trainable_weights,
                                   loss=loss)

        self.train_fn = K.function(inputs=[self.model.input,
                                           action_onehot_placeholder,
                                           discount_reward_placeholder],
                                   outputs=[],
                                   updates=updates)
```